# Absolute of Second Derivative of f is less than or equal to M

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value, rolles-theorem

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function

1. Suppose $|f''(x)| \leq M$ on $[a, b]$. Show that for all $x \in [a, b]$
   $$|f'(x)| \leq \left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|+(b-a)M$$
2. Suppose that $|f''(x)| \leq M$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{f(x)}$ exists. Show that
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{f'(x)}=0$$

I know we have to use the Mean Value theorem, as we know from that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, but that is for a specific value $c$ and not for all values $x \in [a, b]$.

How does this relate to the $|f''(x)| \leq M$ on $[a, b]$?

Comment: Nice problem !...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for 1**:

By MVT, it's clear that
$$ \left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right| = f'(c),$$
for some $c \in (a,b)$.

Note that
$$ |f'(x)| - |f'(c)| \leq |f'(x)-f'(c)| = |f''(c_0)||x-c| \leq M(b-a)\,\text{ for some } c_0 \in (x, c).$$
Add to both sides $|f'(c)|$. Hence proved.